# Looping over matrix elements in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I would like to name matrix elements according to a loop in R. I didn't succeed by using the following command nor simply using `paste0("M", u)`.

```
for (u in 1:3) {
assign(paste0("M", u)) <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=10)
}
```

I've got the message: `Error in paste0("M", u) <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10) :  destino de la asignación se expande a un objeto fuera del lenguaje`

Comment: `assign(paste0("M", u), matrix(nrow=10, ncol=10) )`

Comment: Creating separate objects only makes things more difficult if you want to process them similarly. Use an array or a list instead, e.g. `M.array <- replicate(3, matrix(NA, 10, 10))` or `M.list <- replicate(3, matrix(NA, 10, 10), simplify=FALSE)`. Then you can refer to the first matrix as `M[ , , 1]` for the array or `M[[1]]` for the list.